# How to disable security in Spring-Boot 2?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

In spring-boot-1.x I had the following configuration to disable the basic security in dev mode:

```
application.properties:
security.basic.enabled=false

application-test.properties:
security.basic.enabled=true

application-prod.properties:
security.basic.enabled=true
```

As of spring-boot-2.x the property is no longer supported. How can I achieve the same configuration (=disable any security related features and configuration in default profile)?

Comment: you need write configuration class

Comment: Could you provide an example of a configuration class that disabled security globally? And how to load it only for the default profile??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is configuration class. here permit for all url:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "app.security.basic.enabled", havingValue = "false")
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
}
```

Comment: So and how can I automatically enable it in default profile, and disable it in test/prod?

Comment: i know , there is no properties configuraiton for spring-security in version 2. you can manage it to read properties file

Comment: I added `@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "app.security.basic.enabled", havingValue = "false")`, in this case the configuration will load. If there is no better way, it works at least.